# Qt directory error message-- error: +: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, qt5

I am using Qt5. I have imported some external openCV libraries to my .pro file.

When I compile my program, I get only one error message saying "error: +: No such file or directory"

Does anybody perhaps know what this error means. If i click on it, it does not refer me to a line in my code so I'm not quite sure where my error is?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your .pro file(s)

Comment: I managed to fix the problem... Thank you though:)